# sticky position is not working only on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, position, sticky

I've faced some weird problem and I've surfed the net for the solution but I haven't found one. I've written a code for a sticky cafe-shop menu that works perfectly in a separate HTML file but when I put it in an HTML box within one of my WordPress theme pages, it only works on a computer and not on mobile...!
I've set no ID and/or class for the tags. All CSS styles are written within the HTML code and not linked outside the code.

```html
<div style="
        width: 100%;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 120px;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 3;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        justify-content: space-between;
      ">
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " href="#cold"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/burg.png" alt="category" />
  </a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#juice"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/milkbanana.png" alt="category" />
  </a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#glace"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/burg.png" alt="category" /></a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#icecream"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/icecream.png" alt="category" /></a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#warm"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/milkbanana.png" alt="category" /></a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#shake"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/icecream.png" alt="category" /></a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#majoon"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/burg.png" alt="category" /></a>
  <a style="
          display: inline;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 36px;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        " class="active" href="#meal"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto" src="https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/milkbanana.png" alt="category" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is the page where the code is used: https://www.behnoosh-cafe.ir/menu4/

Answer (score 0):

this is solved. the problem was that the  had a style of overflow. when I removed it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

be careful with `overflow: hidden` from parent div.
Removing it will likely to make sticky position works again.